# How to determine groups which fulfill certain condition for two consecutive time periods in R

Tags: r, data.table

let's say I have this simple dataset called data:

```
customer_id <- c("1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3")
account_id <- as.character(c(11,11,11,55,55,55,55,38,38,38))
obs_date <- c(as.Date("2017-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2017-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2017-03-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
          as.Date("2017-12-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-01-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-02-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
          as.Date("2018-03-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-04-01","%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2018-05-01","%Y-%m-%d"),
          as.Date("2018-06-01","%Y-%m-%d"))
variable <- c(87,90,100,120,130,150,12,13,15,14)
data <- data.table(customer_id,account_id,obs_date,variable)
```

and I would like to add another variable called indicator, that would equal to 1 for those customer_id, account_id pairs that have variable <= 90 for two or more consecutive observation dates (obs_date) and zero otherwise. Therefore, indicator would be equal to 1 for the first and the third customer_id, account_id pair and it would be like:

```
indicator <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
data <- data.table(customer_id,account_id,obs_date,variable, indicator)
```

Do you please have any ideas how to create this variable called indicator? I need to group by customer_id, account_id and identify those that have variable <= 90 for at least two consecutive time periods.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Wouldn't indicator be 0 for third record because it's variable is 100, which is > 90?

Comment: @samadhi It is per "customer_id, account_id pairs" (not per records/row) and "two or more" rows are sufficient to apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do...

```
data[, v := with(rle(variable <= 90), 
  any(lengths >= 2 & values)
), by=.(customer_id, account_id)]

    customer_id account_id   obs_date variable indicator     v
 1:           1         11 2017-01-01       87         1  TRUE
 2:           1         11 2017-02-01       90         1  TRUE
 3:           1         11 2017-03-01      100         1  TRUE
 4:           2         55 2017-12-01      120         0 FALSE
 5:           2         55 2018-01-01      130         0 FALSE
 6:           2         55 2018-02-01      150         0 FALSE
 7:           2         55 2018-03-01       12         0 FALSE
 8:           3         38 2018-04-01       13         1  TRUE
 9:           3         38 2018-05-01       15         1  TRUE
10:           3         38 2018-06-01       14         1  TRUE
```

To see how it works, look at a simpler line:

```
data[, rle(variable <= 90), by=.(customer_id, account_id)]

   customer_id account_id lengths values
1:           1         11       2   TRUE
2:           1         11       1  FALSE
3:           2         55       3  FALSE
4:           2         55       1   TRUE
5:           3         38       3   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you guys here are amazing! Can I ask what part of the solution makes sure that if I had e.g. the three last rows of "variable" with values 13,100,14 instead of 13,15,14 (i.e. not fulfilling the condition on two consecutive rows), it would have "v" as FALSE for this customer_id, account_id pair? I know it will be correctly FALSE in this case, but I just don't know why. I think I don't understand how this rle() function works.

Comment: @doremi Np :) The rle function will break it down into "runs" of sequential rows where the condition variable <= 90 is met, so there would be three runs with `lengths` of 1 each (with `values` TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), so the `lengths >= 2` condition would fail for all of them. Try `?rle` and `example(rle)`

Answer (score 4):

You could use `dplyr::lag()` (or `data.table::shift()`) to look at the prior value of `variable` in each row, check if each row and prior row are below 90, than see if that's ever true for each group.

```
data[, indicator := max(variable <= 90 & lag(variable) <= 90, na.rm=T), 
     by=.(customer_id, account_id)]
```

`data` is now:

```
    customer_id account_id   obs_date variable indicator
 1:           1         11 2017-01-01       87         1
 2:           1         11 2017-02-01       90         1
 3:           1         11 2017-03-01      100         1
 4:           2         55 2017-12-01      120         0
 5:           2         55 2018-01-01      130         0
 6:           2         55 2018-02-01      150         0
 7:           2         55 2018-03-01       12         0
 8:           3         38 2018-04-01       13         1
 9:           3         38 2018-05-01       15         1
10:           3         38 2018-06-01       14         1
```

To illustrate what's going on:

```
data[, .(obs_date, 
         variable, 
         lag = lag(variable),
         both_below = variable <= 90 & lag(variable) <= 90
       ), by=.(customer_id, account_id)]
```

Output:

```
    customer_id account_id   obs_date variable lag both_below
 1:           1         11 2017-01-01       87  NA         NA
 2:           1         11 2017-02-01       90  87       TRUE
 3:           1         11 2017-03-01      100  90      FALSE
 4:           2         55 2017-12-01      120  NA      FALSE
 5:           2         55 2018-01-01      130 120      FALSE
 6:           2         55 2018-02-01      150 130      FALSE
 7:           2         55 2018-03-01       12 150      FALSE
 8:           3         38 2018-04-01       13  NA         NA
 9:           3         38 2018-05-01       15  13       TRUE
10:           3         38 2018-06-01       14  15       TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for using `lag`, I was trying to answer it that way following an `ifelse`, but it's easier without one.